# Macbook pro shows 26gb storage space but actually has 256gb. What to do?

Tags: macbook-pro, storage

I have what seems to be a big problem for me. My Macbook pro 2017 has 256gb storage but only shows and use 26gb. How can that be? How can I solve it? I can't update it or install apps because I already run out of memory. Please help me.

[image: [1]: ()![enter image description here]]

[image]

Comment: Did you at some point partition your drive? Whats the output if you type "diskutil list" and then hit enter in the terminal or what does the disk utility app show?

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. The mac was not mine so I don't know. I don't understand what the command shows. How can I send a pics to show?

Comment: "mac was not mine" is rather worrying. When you first got it, was it completely wiped & made you run through the initial setup as a new owner [or did you do that yourself]? There are very many reasons you should not just 'adopt' a second hand Mac as your own without totally wiping it first.

Comment: You can simply copy the terminal output from diskutil list and edit this post to paste the text.

Comment: @IconDaemon - it's not so much the lack of remaining space it's that the total size shows as 26GB not 250.

Comment: John - I'm also bothered by the fact the diskutil says "virtual". It should say "synthesized". Launch Disk Utility [from Applications/Utilities] then press Cmd/2 so it shows all devices, not just volumes. Click your volume name BVC X & take a screenshot.

Comment: BTW - to screenshot, press Cmd/Shift/4 then tap the spacebar & click on any window. It will screenshot just that window to the desktop.

Comment: @John What does `diskutil corestorage list` say? (@Tetsujin "virtual" is for Core Storage and "synthesized" is for APFS.)

Comment: @John I suggest you don't pursue the why or attempt to fix. Instead just copy (backup) any important data to an external disk; make sure the username is not using iCloud (linked to an Apple ID); and do a clean install of latest macOS via Internet Recovery on a cleanly erased 256GB disk.  And don't use disk names with funny characters.